# Openshift application goes "idle" with no wake up

Tags: node.js, openshift

Just searched around and found out that an app is turned "idle" after a period of inactivity. The thing is that my app on openshift goes idle even with activity.

Actually, it has been happening for a while but today I noticed that the app turned "idle" twice, and I was working and accessing it during the day, so automatic wake up feature seems non existent.

It's a scalable nodejs v0.10 app.

When I start ssh session I see this message clearly:

```
***  This gear has been temporarily unidled. To keep it active, access
***  your app @ http://xx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com/
```

Comment: When you say activity, do you mean HTTP requests? https://www.openshift.com/faq/what-happens-if-my-application-is-not-used-for-a-long-time#comment-22021

Comment: Would you mind emailing us at Openshift@redhat.com with the url of your application as well as login-id. Myself or one of my colleagues can take a closer look to see what might have caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had been having a couple of problems with this specific issue but it should be resolved now.  Can you please verify if you are still having this issue?

Comment: I deleted the old application and re-created it as a *non-scalable* app. Since then I haven't had this issue, it may be related to "scalable" apps.. maybe not.

Comment: it should not have been.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, and worked with the ops team in #openshift-dev on Freenode IRC to help resolve it.
It should be fixed now: https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status